# PyTorch Lightning - Is Trainer necessary to use multiple GPUs?

Tags: pytorch-lightning

If I want to take advantage of PyTorch Lightning's ability to train using multiple GPUs, do I have to use their Trainer?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use all the Lightning features (even multi-GPU) such as loggers, metrics tracking, and checkpointing, then you would need to use `Trainer`. On the other hand, if you are fine with some limited functionality you can check out the recent [`LightningLite`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/starter/lightning_lite.html).